# qemu-aarch64 networking

Tags: embedded-linux, qemu, binary-emulation

I am wondering whether is it possible to provide network adapter name to `qemu-aarch64` please don't get confused with `qemu-system-aarch64`?
I have a Linux user-space cross compiled application which I can run it using `qemu-aarch64`, but the executable deals with ethernet adapters.

How can I map my host machines `enp0s3` or `enp0s8` physical network adapter to `qemu-aarch64` with name `eth0` or `eth1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qemu-aarch64 just runs a single guest Linux binary. Any system calls made by the guest binary (including those dealing with asking about what ethernet interfaces are present) are simply passed to the host; there is no support for changing the answers given.

Network interfaces are entirely renamable in Linux, so (a) a correctly written guest application should not care about what the exact names are and (b) if you are willing to deal with the upheaval you could rename them on the host. I wouldn't really recommend (b) except by running everything inside a VM for this purpose, though :-)